# Structural Array Odd/Even Glitch

Tags: c++, structure

My program generates a text file with random numbers, for eg:

```
123
1234
12345
123456
```

And the program takes in that file and puts the random data into a struct array.
It then processes the array and outputs a file that looks like this:

outfile.txt produced based in the above infile.txt:

```
No      Type Odd Even Sum Digit
1234    Even 2   2    10  4
23467   Odd  2   3    22  5
123     Odd  2   1    6   3
```

But the problem I'm running into is that everything comes out fine and as intended, except that my odd/even count stops working on the every other line! For instance, the first line, it would output the correct results, the second line it wouldn't, the third line it would work again and so on.

```
//oddcount, evencount. (WORKS, BUT ONLY EVERY OTHER LINE)

int countEven;
int countOdd;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    countEven = 0;
    countOdd = 0;
    while (t[i].no > 0)
    {
        if (t[i].no % 2 == 1)
        {
            countOdd++;
            t[i].no/= 10;
        }
        else
        {
            countEven++;
            t[i].no/=10;
        }
        n[i].oddDigits = countOdd;
        n[i].evenDigits = countEven;
    } i++;

}
```

Here is the code in it's entirety.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 100;

enum NumType {Odd, Even};

struct Number
{
    int no;
    NumType type;
    int oddDigits;
    int evenDigits;
    int sumDigits;
    int noDigits;
};

void arrayToOutfile (ofstream&, char [], Number [], int);
void constructInfile (fstream&, char []);
int constructArray (fstream&, char [], Number []);
void processArray (Number [], int);
NumType whatType (int);
void getStringLabel (NumType, char []);

int main ()
{
    srand (time_t(NULL));
    fstream inFile;
    char fileName [MAX];

    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    constructInfile (inFile, fileName);

    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;

    Number n [MAX];

    int size = constructArray(inFile, fileName, n);

    processArray (n, size);

    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;

    ofstream outFile;

    cout << "Enter the output filename: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    arrayToOutfile (outFile, fileName, n, size);
}

void constructInfile (fstream& inFile, char fileName[])
{
    inFile.open (fileName, ios::out);

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << fileName << " cant be created for write"
        << endl;

        exit (-1);
    }

    int size = rand() % 51+ 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        inFile << rand () % 901 + 100 << endl
        << rand () % 90001 + 10000 << endl
        << rand () % 900001 + 100000 << endl;
        i++;
    }

    cout << "written to outfile successfully" << endl;

    inFile.close();

}

int constructArray (fstream& inFile, char fileName[], Number n[])
{
    inFile.open (fileName, ios::in);

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << fileName << " cant be accessed for array creation."
        << endl;
        exit (-1);
    }
    cout << "Begin file to array" << endl;
    int i = 0;
    while (inFile >> n[i].no)
    {
        ++i;
    }

    inFile.close();
    cout << "File to array transfer success" << endl;

    return i;

}

void processArray (Number n [], int size)
{

    cout << "Begin processing array" << endl;
    //Odd or Even Enum Label
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        n[i].type = whatType (n[i].no);
    }


//copy number n array to temp n array
    Number t [MAX];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        t[i].no = n[i].no;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <size; i++)
    {
        n[i].evenDigits = 0;
        n[i].oddDigits = 0;
    }

//oddcount, evencount. (WORKS, BUT ONLY EVERY OTHER LINE)

    int countEven;
    int countOdd;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        countEven = 0;
        countOdd = 0;
        while (t[i].no > 0)
        {
            if (t[i].no % 2 == 1)
            {
                countOdd++;
                t[i].no/= 10;
            }
            else
            {
                countEven++;
                t[i].no/=10;
            }
            n[i].oddDigits = countOdd;
            n[i].evenDigits = countEven;
        } i++;

    }

    //copy number n array to temp n array again.
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        t[i].no = n[i].no;
    }

    //Sum digits    (WORKS!!!)
    //SET TO DEFAULT 0 FOR SUMDIGITS

    for (int i = 0; i <size; i++)
    {
        n[i].sumDigits = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size;)
    {
        while (t[i].no > 0)
        {
            n[i].sumDigits = n[i].sumDigits + t[i].no % 10;
            t[i].no /= 10;
        }i++;
    }

    //copy number n array to temp n array again.
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        t[i].no = n[i].no;
    }
    //SET TO DEFAULT 0 for COUNT DIGITS
    for (int i = 0; i <size; i++)
    {
        n[i].noDigits = 0;
    }

    //DIGIT COUNT
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int countDigits = 0;

        while (t[i].no != 0)
        {
            t[i].no /= 10;
            countDigits++;
        }
        n[i].noDigits = countDigits;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

    }

    cout << "The array was processed" << endl;
}
//Enumerated Number type.
NumType whatType (int n)
{

    if (n % 10 % 2 == 1)
        return Odd;
    else
        return Even;
}
//From Array to Outfile.
void arrayToOutfile (ofstream& outFile, char fileName[], Number n[], int size)
{
    outFile.open (fileName);

    if (!outFile)
    {
        cout << "Array to " << fileName << " failed" << endl;
        exit (-1);
    }

    cout << "Begin from array to " << fileName << endl;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision (3);

   char label [MAX];


    outFile << "No" << "\t"
    << "Type" << "\t"
    << "Odd" << "\t"
    << "Even" << "\t"
    << "Sum" << "\t"
    << "Digit"
    << endl;


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        getStringLabel (n[i].type, label);

        outFile << n[i].no << "\t"
        << label << "\t"
        << n[i].oddDigits << "\t"
        << n[i].evenDigits << "\t"
        << n[i].sumDigits << "\t"
        << n[i].noDigits << endl;
    }

    outFile.close();

    cout << "Array to outfile OK" << endl;
}

//Enumeration String label
void getStringLabel (NumType type, char label[])
{

        switch (type)
    {
        case Odd:   strcpy (label, "Odd");
            break;
        case Even:  strcpy (label, "Even");
            break;
        default:    strcpy (label, "err");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to run your code through codepad.org, but sadly it won't work without a file.

Comment: He gave an example how the file looks like ; ) However, I compiled without the second "i++" int he for-loop and the result was then correct… So Wilbert's solution works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call i++ two times, once within the for(...), the second time in the body of the for loop, after the end of the body of the while.

Comment: Yes that was my first guess too. I checked the modified code and it works, so you're definitely right ;-)

Comment: Thank you, thank you my good sirs. When you've been cramming/coding for 4 days straight, things like that pass you by easily. This was my first post here and I am very satisfied with the way things are run around here. :)